# OpenCL sub buffer alignment

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I have a nested loop structure in which I want to work with a sub buffer of a OpenCL buffer object. However, the sub buffer is not alignment to the `CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN`  of my device (which is 128 Bytes). I used bitwise operation to align the buffer as required by the hardware:

```
cl_mem sub_buff;
for(int u = 0; u < u_max; u++) {
    for (int v = 0; v < v_max; v++) {
       int offset = (u * v_max + v) * (size_of_slice);
       size_t base_align = 128;  // Bytes
       size_t aligned_offset = (offset + base_align - 1) & ~(base_align - 1); // align to next multiple of base_align
       cl_buffer_region subBufferRegion = {aligned_offset,
                                            size_of_slice * sizeof(float)}; 
       i_fft_buff = clCreateSubBuffer(data_buff_d, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                                        CL_BUFFER_CREATE_TYPE_REGION,
                                        &subBufferRegion, &error);
       // ... continue to work with sub buffer
    }
}
```

But doing so, Im missing out on elements because `aligned_offset` is rounding-up to the next multiple of 128 Bytes.

I was wondering if there is a way of aligning the sub buffer to the required 128 Bytes and still getting all `size_of_slice` elements? I don't want to avoid creating a new cl_mem buffer in each iteration.

Comment: Ideally, populate the original buffer with required alignment. As a hack you can generate aligned offset to the previous align offset, and it should cause recomputation of the some values, assuming it doesn't break some of your logic (e.g. if you some up some values)